# working with sparkfun tmp102 temperature sensor over windows 10 IoT

Tags: i2c, sensor, windows-iot

I'm looking for help in communicating with the sparkfun tmp102 sensor via windows 10 IoT UWP app on a raspberry pi 2.

I've already found this tutorial:

https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2016/06/15/how-to-get-the-temperature-using-tmp102-c-and-the-raspberry-pi-3/

but  there is a problem: the GetDeviceId method is not implemented, and I have no idea how can I find the device ID (of the sensor I guess...?). I'll appreciate some help - either a way to get the device ID or a better example..

Comment: Just looking at that example it seems like the GetDeviceId is deliberately not implemented because the device does NOT have an ID. It looks like he is mannaully entering the I2C address somewhere and NOT using the GetDeviceId. Are you just using his code from GitHub? Or did you modify something? The I2C Address just seems to be the PIN. I suspect it only works with one device ?? :(

Comment: Me and my team eventually made it work somehow... I don't have the code here, but we used another example we've with slight changes in the addresses where you write to and read from...

Answer (score 1):

here is an [example code](https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/MMC3316xMT) which explain how you can interface i2c device with raspberry pi and windows IOT. in this example they are using an accelerator, all you will need to do is change the i2c bytes and it will work.